# Define chart range from first to last row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to establish charts that will generate with each worksheet looping.For that, I have gotten the first and last row of a column containing specific text,now how do I create a range  for my chart using the first and last row of Column C to Column D

For example
FirstRow =4
LastRow = 7

I have tried the following and it doesnt seem to work

```
Sub testy()


Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long

a = 4
b = 7

Dim rng As Range
Dim rngVX As Range
Dim rngVY As Range

Set rngVX = Sheet1.Range("C" & a)
Set rngVY = Sheet1.Range("D" & b)


Set rng = Union(rngVX, rngVY)

Debug.Print rngVX
Debug.Print rng.Address



'Debug.Print rng.Address

Dim embeddedchart As ChartObject

Set embeddedchart = Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=180, Width:=300, Top:=7, Height:=200)
embeddedchart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C & a:D" & b)
embeddedchart.Chart.ChartType = xlLine
End Sub
```

The issue when I try to union the range is I am getting C4,D7, I need a continuous range C4:D7.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `Set rng = Range(rngVX, rngVY)` instead. Using `Range` with 2 parameters defines a  contiguous range where the two parameters (in your case `rngVX` and `rngVY`) will define the corners of the range.

Comment: BTW, there are quotes (`"`) missing in `.Range("C & a:D" & b)` it should be: `.Range("C" & a & ":D" & b)`